# Change console color in Mozilla Firefox Web Developer theme

Tags: css, firefox, themes, firefox-developer-tools

Does anybody know how I can style the Firefox built-in Web Developer (devtools) theme?  I am using the Dark theme, and need to make a small change in the way line numbers/column numbers are shown in the console output.

The default color, which is a shade of orange, to my eyes is totally unreadable.
I searched the web but all I get is stuff about theming of code that is displayed and analyzed *by* Web Developer.

[image]

Btw., I have to use the dark theme because the lighter themes are even more of a strain on my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/client/themes/webconsole.css) might be what you're looking for. It's the main CSS file for the dev tools. The dark theme is defined [here](http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/client/themes/dark-theme.css) and the used orange is defined [here](http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/c477aa8bd99278962998adba1c5e4b15a02c42c7/devtools/client/themes/variables.css#42).

I'm not sure if that color can be changing without rebuilding Firefox or creating a browser extension for that.

Comment: Thanks. The second url you provided led me to a css3 variable '--theme-highlight-orange'.
Just for laughs I added this to my  $HOME/.mozilla/firefox/matd0hrs.default/chrome/userChrome.css:


`/*  Styles for Web developer tools */
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
* {  --theme-highlight-orange: #D9C329 !important; }`

Guess what, it works!